# Send mail from localhost via Symfony2 Command using Swiftmailer

Tags: php, symfony, email, command-line, swiftmailer

**Command function**

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance('test')
            ->setContentType("text/html")
            ->setFrom('x@x.com')
            ->setTo('x@gmail.com');

        $message->setBody('test');

        if ($this->getApplication()->getKernel()->getContainer()->get('mailer')->send($message))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
```

When I execute command in Command Line I get true like mail is sent.

**Paramters.yml**

```
mailer_transport: gmail
mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
mailer_user: x@gmail.com
mailer_password: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

**Config.yml**

```
swiftmailer:
    spool:
        type: file
        path: "%kernel.root_dir%/../swiftmailer"
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    host:      %mailer_host%
    username:  %mailer_user%
    password:  %mailer_password%
```

I had read somewhere that Symfony Profiler can be used to see if mail has sent but I just want to physically send mail to my address in testing purpose. I just need info where I do wrong things.

I must **notice** that I using **allowed device security tool** in gmail account.

Can that be reason why mail is not sent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes! I found a solution.

I had removed spool in  **Config.yml** and add port and encryption.

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    host:      %mailer_host%
    port:      %mailer_port%
    encryption: %mailer_encryption%
    username:  %mailer_user%
    password:  %mailer_password%
```

and in **Parameters.yml**

```
mailer_transport: gmail
mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
mailer_port: 465
mailer_encryption: ssl
mailer_user: yourMail@gmail.com
mailer_password: yourNewGeneratedAppPassword
```

after that I was available to see errors using

```
 $mailer = $this->getContainer()->get('mailer');

 $logger = new \Swift_Plugins_Loggers_ArrayLogger();
 $mailer->registerPlugin(new \Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin($logger));
```

Then after message is sent I had used:

```
 echo $logger->dump();
```

To print error in terminal.

**Below is whole function.**

```
public function sendMail($email, $data)
    {
        $mailer = $this->getContainer()->get('mailer');

        $logger = new \Swift_Plugins_Loggers_ArrayLogger();
        $mailer->registerPlugin(new \Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin($logger));

        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance('test')
            ->setContentType("text/html")
            ->setFrom('x@mdpi.com')
            ->setTo($email);

        $message->setBody($data);

        if ($mailer->send($message))
        {
            echo $logger->dump();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**Tips:**

Also you must authenticate your app, ofcourse if you using gmail.
via this link ***https://myaccount.google.com/security***

There is link

> app password

Here is description **https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en**

After click there you will need to give custom name to your app and generate new password which you will using in

> Parameters.yml >> mailer_password:

to connect app with gmail account.